# Support different types on overloaded operators?

Tags: c++

I have a doubt, its correct to suport operators for different types of a custom class?
Suppose we have this:

```
template<class T>
class C { /* Class implemantation */ }

int main () {

    C<int> someObject;
    C<double> otherObject;

    std::cout << someObject + otherObject;

}
```

It's correct to support the operator+ for a C object ot type int and a C object of type double?

Comment: Does C support both types in general?  Is there a meaningful way to implement the `+` operator for both types?

Comment: It's up to you. You can make it work automatically. You can make it so the user needs to make a static_cast (conversion operator). Or you can disallow it. The problem with automatic is which type should get priority?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or its logically correct or not depends on how you, the class designer, want your classes to be used. Does it make logical sense to add `someObject` and `otherObject`? It makes sense to add `2` and `3.5`, but that says nothing about whether that's right for your code. As a counter-example, you cannot add a `basic_string<char>` and a `basic_string<wchar>` - that addition wouldn't make sense since you have to store characters of the same type - but you *can* add two `basic_string<T>`, for any `T`.

You can certainly write the code to do that though, with the `??` to be determined.

```
template <typename T>
class C {
    ..
    template <typename U>
    C<??> operator+(const C<U>& rhs) {
        // ..
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, its was very enlightening. For a first moment I think I should only work with objects of the same type and only suports operators for the same type too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a particular operator to act on specialisation of your class for certain types, you can always write a specialised operator overload, for example:

```
template<class T>
class C { /* implementation */ };

C<double> operator+ (C<int> a, C<double> b)
{
  C<double> ret;
  // Do something to ret given a and b
  return ret;
}

// Lets make it commutative (is that the right word?)
C<double> operator+ (C<double> a, C<int> b)
{
  return b + a;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  C<int> a;
  C<double> b;

  C<double> ret1 = a + b;
  C<double> ret2 = b + a;

  return 0;
}
```

It just depends on what behaviour you want to achieve.

Comment: Hey! Thanks! Its very helpful. There is some way to achieve your sugestion without a template specialization?

Comment: Perhaps, but it depends on exactly what you want to do.